# User verification

Tags: security, users, password, setuid

Suppose I've writen a setuid root executable and I want it to verify that the user is not a script by asking the user to provide his/her password (granted, users might save their password and use that in a script, but that doesn't concern me).

What would be a good way to do this? The more portable the better.

Comment: perhaps checking the Stdin/stdout whether its attached to terminal `[ -t 0 ]`

Comment: Don't you want to pull authentication to apropriate level, do it in unix way: let script alone and configure 'sudo' or similar tool?

Comment: @paul I don't want to needlessly make users into sudoers. All I want is to have them verify themselves (with their password) for my app.

Comment: @PSkocik sudo is very flexible, you'll register your program and allow _everyone_ to run it requiring password. You don't allow users to be root in this way.

Comment: Thanks then. I'll go read the manual. If you've got a code snippet that solves the problem right away, I've got 25 points going your way. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most modern Unix systems use [PAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluggable_authentication_module) to handle authentication. The `pam_unix` module is the one that does password authentication against `/etc/password` and `/etc/shadow`.

However, you shouldn't reinvent the wheel. Asking for the user's password and running as root is a basic configuration of [sudo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo), the de facto standard way to elevate privileges. Note that properly elevating privileges is tricky: did you remember to purge all environment variables that could affect your program? Sudo takes pains to do it safely.

To allow user `alice` to run `/usr/local/bin/myprogram` as root with any arguments of her choice after typing her password, use the following line in the `sudoers` file (the sudo configuration file):

```
alice ALL = (root) /usr/local/bin/myprogram
```

To edit the `sudoers` file, run the command `visudo`.

Alice will have to run `sudo myprogram`. If you want her to be able to type just the program name, hide this in a wrapper script. But note that Alice may prefer to run something like `gksudo myprogram` to get a GUI prompt.

Many variations are possible, including forbidding the caller from passing arguments:

```
alice ALL = (root) /usr/local/bin/myprogram ""
```

or applying the entry to a group:

```
%mygroup ALL = (root) /usr/local/bin/myprogram
```

If your program needs to know who invoked it, sudo makes that available in the environment variables `SUDO_UID` and `SUDO_USER`.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for something like this

(bash):

```
hash=$(sudo cat /etc/shadow |grep "^$USER:" |cut -d: -f2) 
cmphash=$(mkpasswd -m sha-512 -S "$(echo "$hash" | cut -d '$' -f3)")
cmp <(echo "$hash") <(echo "$cmphash") && echo "Correct password!"
```

This works but harcodes the hash method which somehow identified by
the number in `echo "$hash" | cut -d '$' -f2` which is 6 in this case.
I have yet to figure out how to map the number to the hash method.